# embedded python loaded from .dll

Tags: python, c++, dll

I'm loading an embedded Python (3.5.2) in a .dll compiled with Visual Studio Express 15.  This .dll is called from a LabView program. I can call a simple routine in a Python script which does a multiply of two ints and returns the result to LabView.  The weirdness begins when I try to run a complex routine that does Numpycalls, calls to camera code and calls  into Theano code. The end result returned from Python will still be an integer value.

When i try to debug the .dll the PyObjects returned from the various calls have strange refcnts(huge).  So my first question is does the compiler have to be set to a specific alignment for structures?  If I create a new tuple and pass it 2 values should i expect the PyObject to have a refcnt of 1?
Getting ready to download Python source and start wading through but maybe someone can help out

Comment: lease read [ask] and [mcve] and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: Since your question is deluged with answers, I'm sure you can ignore my advice. And as you mentioned `I am certainly not going to post a giant piece of code` seems you didn't bother to read and internalize [mcve]. Lastly, being as polite as you are to other stackoverflowers who tried to help a newbie on the site, I'm sure if your attitude stays the same - your stay here will be very pleasant and fruitful: people will just beat a path to your account to answer the questions of such a pleasant and courteous person.

Comment: Some actual useful information for others that may be trying to embed a Python interpreter.  When building the debug version it is important to define Py_DEBUG so that the definition of PyObject agree between the Python code and your .dll code. I am able now to debug from my .dll into Python code(I downloaded source and symbols for 3.5) as well as do mixed debugging and step through my Python script. Visual Studio PTVS set to  mixed mode works nicely.  By putting my .dll project and a Python script project into 1 Solution I can seamlessly step from C to Python interpreter and back.   very cool